# How to prevent line break in listitems of asp:bulletedlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am displaying some content in this list from other source.but due to the length of text,some list items automatically having line breaks.How can I prevent this?
Here is my list :

```
<asp:BulletedList DisplayMode="LinkButton" OnClick="lstDirs_Click" id="lstDirs"  runat="server" ></asp:BulletedList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a css class to the list control:

```
<asp:BulletedList CssClass="dirsList" ...
```

And then define the necessary CSS to make sure individual items in this list do not break the line. You would use `white-space: nowrap;` for that. Be aware that this needs to be applied to the individual items, that is to the `li` in the output markup. So, in your css file:

```
.dirsList li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: nice answer support from me (y)